# Prove that $ \prod_{a\in I} A_a$ it's dense in $ \prod_{a\in I} X_a$

Tags: general-topology

Hello I have problems with this exercise

Let $\{X_a \} a \in I$ an arbitrary collection of topological spaces. Prove that $  \prod_{a\in I} A_a$ it's dense in $  \prod_{a\in I} X_a$ if and only if $A_a$ is dense in $X_a$ for each $a \in I$

I need a hint

Thanks

Comment: Show that if the sets $A_\alpha$ are dense in their respective spaces, then every basic open set in the product intersects their product. For the other direction show that if some $A_\beta$ is not dense in $X_\beta$, there is a basic open set in the product that does not intersect $\prod_\alpha A_\alpha$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continuous image of a dense set is dense in the image. Apply this to the projections to see one direction.

For the other it suffices to show that any non-empty basic open subset of the product (recall what’s form that takes) intersects the product of the dense sets and this should be easy to see.

Comment: I can't understand. This part Apply this to the projections to see one direction.

Comment: @manuelcerda suppose the product is dense. What is its image under the projection $\pi_i$?

Comment: Please inform yourself, Henno, about a new site policy now in operation: [Enforcing of Quality Control](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?noredirect=1#comment153047_33508).  Answerers are now held accountable when they answer poor quality questions.